# Is there any fast and efficient way to get abstracts from pubmed?

Tags: biopython, pubmed

I would like to download large scientific abstract data for lets say about 2000 Pubmed IDs. My python code is sloppy and seems rather slow working. Is there any fast and efficient method to do harvest these abstracts?

If this is the fastest method how do I measure it so I become able compare against others or home against work situation (different ISP may play part in speed)?

Attached my code below.

```
import sqlite3
from Bio.Entrez import read,efetch,email,tool
from metapub import PubMedFetcher
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import  date
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import time
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
Abstract_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name","pmid","abstract"])

def abstract_download(self,dict_pmids):
    """
        This method returns abstract for a given pmid and add to the abstract data
    """
    index=0
    baseUrl = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/"
    for names in dict_pmids:
        for pmid in dict_pmids[names]:
            try:
                abstract = []
                url = baseUrl+"efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id="+pmid+"&rettype=xml"+
                response=requests.request("GET",url,timeout=500).text
                response=response.encode('utf-8')
                root=ET.fromstring(response)
                root_find=root.findall('./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/')
                if len(root_find)==0:
                    root_find=root.findall('./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle')
                for i in range(len(root_find)):
                    if root_find[i].text != None:
                        abstract.append(root_find[i].text)
                if abstract is not None:
                    Abstract_data.loc[index]=names,pmid,"".join(abstract)
                index+=1
            except:
                print "Connection Refused"
                time.sleep(5)
                continue
    return Abstract_data
```

> EDIT: The general error that occurs for this script is seemingly a "Connection Refused". See the answer of ZF007 below how this was solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems like a better fit for biostars.org or https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stedy The question, although missing some information as the imported modules and the error or the problem with the code shown, seems to be a `requests` question. The biological context is secondary and therefore has a place at stack overflow IMO.

Comment: @Nishal Could you add to your questions the modules imported and also what seems to be the error/problem with your code?

Comment: @rodgdor Yes, good observation

Comment: I am importing requests,xml modules

Comment: If you have a list of all IDs, just make one POST request with the IDs as a semi-colon separated string. Reference:
 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/ , search for `UID list`.

Comment: @Nishal.. As rodgdor and Maximilian Peter requested add the imports and other code to run your script example propperly. I assume you added something like a `time start` and `time stop` with a time delta to show total time ran. Can you provide specific IDs that are downloaded.. I don't see them in your script and thus not able to reproduce your result! If provided we can test-run your code and see if time delta is more or less in 2sigma or that its just your ISP connection to pubmed that may be the challenge at hand here? For now the code looks fine to me.

Comment: @ZF007 . Added imported modules to the code.

Comment: @ Nishal... can you please post the 2000 pubmed IDs in a separate file in an asnwer or as attachment to the question of your post... ? This way it will not distract from the main question at hand but am I able to do some testing from my side here.... okay?

Comment: @Nishal....to make it easy and batchwise...just something like this "PMID: 21491000-21493000" will do, or your range you had in mind or if its all separate PMIDs..then as above requested.

Comment: @ZF007 will test the code and let you know.

Comment: @Nishal... it wasn't a pubmed entrez connection issue. See my answer below. Can you please post a very short dict_pmid list of tops 5 pmid in the format your script requires so that you or me can post an additional "clean" answer without the inline comment? This helps to complete the answer and the post itself. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works. Your script hang on malformed URL construction. Also if things went wrong inside the script the response was a refused connection. This was infact not the case because it was the code that did the processing of the retrieved data.. I've made some adjustments to get the code working for me and left comments in place where you need to adjust due to the lack of the dict_pmids list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, time, requests, sqlite3

import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from metapub import PubMedFetcher
from datetime import  date
from Bio.Entrez import read,efetch,email,tool


def abstract_download(pmids):

    """
        This method returns abstract for a given pmid and add to the abstract data
    """

    index   = 0
    baseUrl = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/"
    collected_abstract = []

    # code below diabled to get general abstract extraction from pubmed working. I don't have the dict_pmid list.

    """
    for names in dict_pmids:
        for pmid in dict_pmids[names]:

    move below working code to the right to get it in place with above two requirements prior to providing dict_pmid list.

    # from here code works upto the next comment. I don't have the dict_pmid list.
    """

    for pmid in pmids:

        print 'pmid : %s\n' % pmid

        abstract  = []
        root = ''

        try:

            url       = '%sefetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=%s&rettype=xml' % (baseUrl, pmid)
             # checks my url... line to parse into a webbrowser like firefox.
            print 'url', url

            response  = requests.request("GET", url, timeout=500).text
             # check if I got a response.
            print 'response', response

#                response  = response.encode('utf-8')
            root      = ET.fromstring(response)

        except Exception as inst:
            # besides a refused connection.... the "why" it was connected comes in handly to resolve issues at hand
            # if and when they happen.
            print "Connection Refused", inst

            time.sleep(5)
            continue

        root_find = root.findall('./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/')

        if len(root_find)==0:

                root_find = root.findall('./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle')

        # check if I found something
        print 'root_find : %s\n\n' % root_find

        for i in range(len(root_find)):

            if root_find[i].text != None:

                abstract.append(root_find[i].text)

        Abstract_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name","pmid","abstract"])

        # check if I found something
        #print 'abstract : %s\n' % abstract

        # code works up to the print statement ''abstract', abstract' teh rest is disabled because I don't have the dict_pmid list.

        if abstract is not None:

#                Abstract_data.loc[index] = names,pmid,"".join(abstract)

            index += 1
            collected_abstract.append(abstract)

    # change back return Abstract_data when dict_pmid list is administered.
#    return Abstract_data
    return collected_abstract

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sys.stdout.flush()

    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

    pubmedIDs = range(21491000, 21491001)

    mydata = abstract_download(pubmedIDs)

    print 'mydata : %s' % (mydata)
```